# Blockify won't run

Tags: xubuntu, spotify, mute

[Blockify](https://github.com/mikar/blockify) mutes Spotify during ad's.

I installed it through the **fixed version** (`ctrl-f` the link) on to Xubuntu. When I tried to run Blockify from the terminal (having already run Spotify), I got:

`No handlers could be found for logger "util"
2015-07-26 07:44:23 ERROR    main     No spotify process found. Exiting.`

despite Spotify running. I next installed the **master branch**, and when I tried to run it i got:

`No handlers could be found for logger "util"
2015-07-26 07:49:44 ERROR    util     Could not parse option start_spotify for section general. Using default value.
2015-07-26 07:49:44 ERROR    main     No spotify process found.
2015-07-26 07:49:44 ERROR    main     Exiting.`

Thanks for reading, it's all yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to jump through some hoops to get spotify running, and it turns out i had the wrong version installed. I Installed another version using [these steps](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-Spotify-onto-UbuntuDebianLinux/), and Blockify now runs.

On the other hand, this version of spotify looks a sight worse (invisible friend's feed, white square in the middle), though I have been able to get playlists going. Hopefully it's fixable.